# Get conditional value from previous node

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have this XSLT 2.0 template:

```
<xsl:template match="footnote">
    <xsl:variable name = "string" select="./text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name = "bool">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$string = preceding::footnote/text()">
                <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="$bool = 'true'">
        <xsl:variable name="footnoteCount">
            <xsl:call-template name="getItemNumber">
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
    <!-- DO XSL-FO TRANSFORMATION STUFF-->
    </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:if test="$bool = 'false'">
        <xsl:variable name = "footnoteCount">
            <xsl:if test="$string = preceding::footnote/text()">
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding::footnote/$footnoteCount"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!--DO XSL-FO TRANSFORMATION STUFF-->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Edited sample XML. I'd like to transform this:

```
<footnote>Foo bar</footnote>
<footnote>Bar foo</footnote>
<footnote>Foo bar</footnote>
<footnote>Foo bar</footnote>
<footnote>Bar</footnote>
<footnote>Foo</footnote>
```

Into this:

```
<footnote>Foo bar</footnote>
<footnote>Bar foo</footnote>
<footnote>Bar</footnote>
<footnote>Foo</footnote
```

And then stylise it using XSL-FO. The aim of this styling is that text in the main body will have a numbered reference, which is represented by `$footnotecount`, to the footnote which is then rendered at the bottom of the page. I need to transform the document so that duplicate footnates are only rendered once and that the number reference (`$footnoteCount`) is the same for each duplicate.

So what I'm trying to do with this template is:

1. Determine whether a footnote element with the current node's text already exists.
2. If it doesn't exist (i.e, '$bool' is 'true') , find the previous footnote's number, increment it (this is done in the 'getItemNumber' template) and create a 'new' footnote. If it does exist ($bool is 'false'), get the $footnoteCount variable of the node that the text matches and use it for the current node.

It's the scenario in which the footnote already exists that I'm having trouble with. I have no idea how to get the $footnoteCount variable from a previous, specific node dependent on whether than node meets a certain criteria (whether its text is the same as the $string variable in the current node). It's being made more difficult by the fact that the $footnoteCount variable only exists conditionally (even if in practice it will always exist since $bool has to be either true or false).

Does anyone have advice on what to do here?

Comment: Can you please post `getItemNumber` template as well. Once if I come to know what are you intending to do, I can optimize the code!

Comment: I don't think the getItemNumber template is that relevant to the question - it just generates a number that is used if a footnote with the current node's text doesn't already exist. I'm more concerned with what's happening when a footnote with the current node's text does already exist.

Plus, the getItemNumber template calls about three other templates and if I posted them all then this question would become quite convoluted. :)

Comment: Are you using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0?

Comment: Also, just to clarify.... If you have `Footnote 1, Footnote 2, Footnote 4`, would the output be `Footnote 1, Footnote 2, Footnote 3`?

Comment: No, the `Footnote 1, Footnote 2` stuff is just placeholder data - in practice it'll just be any string. The idea is to get rid of 'duplicate' footnotes, not to order them by the number that appears in the text.

Comment: `<xsl:if test="$string = preceding::footnote./text()"><xsl:value-of select="preceding::footnote./$footnoteCount"/>` these two lines are wrong! there is an additional `.` in the code which is not required!

Comment: What you say you want is known as grouping. Just use properly `<xsl:for-each-group>`. And in any language avoid writing `if(x >5) myVar = true; else myVar=false;` This is simply: `myVar = (x > 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a grouping problem, and in XSLT2.0 you can make use of the **xsl:for-each-group** element to get the distinct elements

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="footnote" group-by=".">
```

I think you need a different approach to do your numbering. Firstly you could create a variable to hold a 'look-up' of footnote descriptions and their index

```
    <xsl:variable name="footnotes">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//footnote" group-by=".">
            <footnote id="{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </footnote>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
```

This means the **footnotes** variable contains the following elements

```
<footnote id="1">Foo bar</footnote>
<footnote id="2">Bar foo</footnote>
<footnote id="3">Bar</footnote>
<footnote id="4">Foo</footnote>
```

Then, to replace your existing **footnote** elements with numeric references, you would have a template like this

```
    <xsl:template match="footnote">
        <footnote>
            <xsl:value-of select="$footnotes/footnote[. = current()]/@id"/>
        </footnote>
    </xsl:template>
```

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="footnotes">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//footnote" group-by=".">
            <footnote id="{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </footnote>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="footnote"/>

        Footnotes
        <xsl:copy-of select="$footnotes"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="footnote">
        <footnote>
            <xsl:value-of select="$footnotes/footnote[. = current()]/@id"/>
        </footnote>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML (assuming a root element), the following is output

```
<footnote>1</footnote>
<footnote>2</footnote>
<footnote>1</footnote>
<footnote>1</footnote>
<footnote>3</footnote>
<footnote>4</footnote>

Footnotes
<footnote id="1">Foo bar</footnote>
<footnote id="2">Bar foo</footnote>
<footnote id="3">Bar</footnote>
<footnote id="4">Foo</footnote>
```

Comment: Thank you for the well thought out answer, but this doesn't appear to solve my problem of needing to get the value of the $footnoteCount variable in the matching footnode nodes. If it was just an issue of getting rid of the duplicates then my code already does that (although not as tidily as yours, granted).

Comment: Perhaps you could amend your sample XML to be contain more representative data (i.e where the input sample doesn't contain any numbering, if that is the case)? Thanks!

Comment: I've changed the XML, and added a paragraph below explaining exactly what I need to do with this stylesheet.

Comment: This was a huge help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As well as failing to use xsl:for-each-group, there are many other things wrong with your code. For example, take this:

```
<xsl:variable name = "bool">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$string = preceding::footnote/text()">
            <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

You can write that as

```
<xsl:variable name="bool" as="xs:boolean()" 
    select="$string = preceding::footnote"/>
```

Then you do this:

```
<xsl:if test="$bool = 'true'">
    <xsl:variable name="footnoteCount">
        <xsl:call-template name="getItemNumber">
            <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:if>
```

which is completely useless: the variable goes out of scope as soon as it is declared, so it can never be referenced.

You need to do some background reading about XSLT, there are a lot of ideas you haven't yet grasped.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the tip on the boolean. Secondly, it doesn't go out of scope as soon as it is declared - as I say in the comment I put in my question, I 'DO XSL-FO TRANSFORMATION STUFF' in the same if block. The XSL-FO transformation stuff makes frequent use of the footnoteCount variable. There are quite a few ideas about XSLT that I haven't grasped - that's why I'm asking about it on here. There is only so much that reading can help you with. This isn't a very constructive answer.